# After using -s JOBDIR parameter, does Scrapy run the start_requests function in the spider when resuming the spider process?

Tags: scrapy

After using -s JOBDIR parameter, does Scrapy run the start_requests function in the spider when resuming the spider process?

I searched the Scrapy documentation related to start_requests and Jobs, but found no mention of this. When I tested it myself, I found that Scrapy does rerun the start_requests function when resuming the spider process. Is this behavior expected?

Comment: It needs to check if all of the requests generated from the start_urls have already run through the engine and returned responses.  So yah